# Can't get Grok parsing rule in Datadog work

Tags: logging, datadog

I've got raw text logs of different levels that all get ingested as `ERROR` in Datadog. F.e. this line:

```
[2023-05-31T09:20:05.832Z INFO  scheduler::job::webhook] Attempting webhook for job 'sale' of tx TxId(99774)
```

gets parsed as `ERROR`. I saw in the docs that I can add a new pipeline and add Grok processing rules for my logs. Unfortunately, I cannot get it to work.

This is what I've come up with:

```
status_and_service \[%{date("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ"):date_time}\s%{word:log_status}\s%{GREEDYDATA:service_name}\]\s%{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

I'm getting this error in the parser composer:
[image]

Comment: You can try this pattern: `\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\s%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\s\s%{GREEDYDATA:service_name}\]\s%{GREEDYDATA:message}`